# Why is electrostatics necessary when charges are invariant

Tags: electrostatics

Electrostatics - Electric charges are invariant . Charge on a body does not vary with speed . That is speed at rest = speed in motion .. If this is so , why is it that we are learning a separate branch for stationary charges .. Why not put both stationary charges and charges in motion as one single branch .

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that charges don't change when put into motion, but moving charges produce additional forces beyond electrostatic forces. These forces are called [magnetic forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force). Since it is easier to learn about one kind of force in isolation, [electrostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatics) is usually taught first, then [magnetostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostatics) is introduced, then fully general [electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism) is taught.

Answer (score 1):

Electrostatics is taught first so as we are able to understand Electric forces completely as ,if charges are in motion they produce magnetic field along with electric field also coulomb's law is completely valid only if both charges are at rest and partially valid if one charge is moving. After electrostatics we will study about moving charge which is Electric current then we will study about magnetic field which is produced by a moving charge & electro-magnetic Induction EMI.